# NullReferenceException with defined custom type?

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am working on a C# cross-platform mobile app, based on the Xamarin Framework. The following code uses the [`Monkey.Robotics`](https://github.com/xamarin/Monkey.Robotics/) plugin, which defines the `IAdapter` type. This code compiles, but when run I get the following NullReference error message, even though `adapter` is defined at the top of the program. What am I missing?

```
public partial class HomePage : ContentPage
{

    // Class Definitions 
    ObservableCollection<IDevice> devices;
    IAdapter adapter;

    public HomePage(IAdapter adapter)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.adapter = adapter;
        this.devices = new ObservableCollection<IDevice>();

        Debug.WriteLine ("Before Button Clicked");
        NewDeviceButton.Clicked += async (sender, e) => {

            adapter.StartScanningForDevices (0x133D.UuidFromPartial ()); //Scan for a specific device
            await Task.Delay (2000); // wait 2 seconds for the scan to complete
            adapter.StopScanningForDevices ();
        };


        adapter.DeviceDiscovered += (object sender, DeviceDiscoveredEventArgs e) => {
            Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
                devices.Add (e.Device);
            });
        };
    }
}
```

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>     at My_App.HomePage..ctor (IAdapter adapter) [0x00081] in /Projects/my_App/My_App/Views/HomePage.xaml.cs:72

NB: line 72 is the `adapter.DeviceDiscovered` line.

This is `app.cs` where my `HomePage` is called from:

```
public class App : Application
{
    static IAdapter Adapter;

    public App ()
    {   
        MainPage = new HomePage (Adapter);
    }

    public static void SetAdapter (IAdapter adapter) {
        Adapter = adapter;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, it looks like no instance of adapter being passed to the `HomePage` constructor. Are you using some DI container? Or creating instance of `HomePage` manually and missed appropriate argument?

Comment: Ok, but does `SetAdapter` ever being called? If not - it remains uninitialized. Habe you debugged it?

Comment: Ahh, got it thanks @AndyKorneyev I need this line: `App.SetAdapter (Adapter.Current);` in my AppDeleagate file in the platform specific project. It is the Cross-platform structure which got me! Thank you for youe help.

Comment: ^ And it must be before new app is called